# MySQL Connector 8.0 C++ Error: "CDK: Failed string conversion"

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, string, mysql-connector

I recently installed the MySQL connector 8.0 for C++. I've been trying to use the tutorial codes to run a basic example of a connection (create instance of the 'Session' class), but I keep getting this error when providing the constructor parameters for the class.

While the documentation states that only const& strings are used in the constructor, the Connector actually has an own implementation of a string wrapper (mysqlx::abi2::r0::string), which apparently is supposed to convert strings of chars to whatever format the API uses. However, every time I try to construct one of these objects, a 'fromUTF8' function is triggered and some sort of error occurs (hence the title). I can't check the implementation of the function since it's inside a DLL.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or at least what causes it? I already tried initializing this wrapper with other supported explicit conversion options that the library offers (std::u16string), but then I get a 'bad array length' exeception.

```
#include <mysqlx/xdevapi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace mysqlx;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Session sess("host", 3306, "root", "1234");
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're building in Debug mode? The MySQL libraries are built in Release mode, and mixing them up causes this error. Change your project settings to Release and it should work. For building in Debug, see [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html) guide